# How can I be consistent in Snooker?

Tags: training, performance, snooker

I've been playing Snooker for more than 4 months. Sometimes I can pull some decent performance off, other times I find myself struggling even with the simplest shots. It is like one day I can see clearly the point I have to aim at and I can cue perfectly straight, the following day I can't visualise the shots and if I aim for one side of an object ball, the cue ball will end up hitting it on the other side.

So how can I become more consistent?

Comment: I have exactly the same situation here. One day I get over the table and I already know I've lost my aiming again. It has happened twice that I had a superb aiming for a week or so and then lost it. I'm afraid I can't answer why, and it is really annoying. Did you get your aiming back? Any advice please? Thanks, good luck!

Comment: I'm experimenting with different aiming techniques. I've always been sceptical about focusing on the contact point of the object ball, but since I had nothing to lose, and apparently this is a widely employed aiming method, I decided to give it a try. I was surprised by how natural it felt the first time I tried it. I think my potting rate went up considerably. But like any other aiming technique I've tried so far, this has the tendency to come and go as well, although it seems to perform better than the others even in this situation. Also I wear glasses, so extra handicap on my gameplay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building consistency in snooker (and actually doing anything) is all about progressively adding complexity to the shots you practice.

A straight blue off the spot into the centre pocket is easy, right? So practice it until it becomes second nature. Once it is, progress to a thick 3/4 ball. Then 1/2 ball. Then 1/4 ball. Practice each step until you can make the shot consistently every time and the shot becomes a matter of muscle memory more than conscious effort. If you can't make the shot consistently every time, go back a stage, get that right and come back to it. Reduce the number of variables, get it right then add the complexity back one step at a time.

It's a hell of a lot of work, but the reason the pros make it look so easy is because they are pros - they practice solidly 8 hours a day.

I would add two other suggestions...

1. Make practicing fun. Make practicing it's own game if you can.
2. Don't beat yourself up it doesn't go well. We all have off days, and this goes for everything we do; work, driving the car, cleaning the house. I find that even the smallest irritation can affect my practice. Did I get enough sleep? Did I pay that bill? Have I done that thing I said I'd do? It all adds up. So relax and allow yourself the off days.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>NOTE: My answer is not specific to snooker, but attempts to provide insight toward what, I believe, you are experiencing.</sub>

Consistency comes from **practice, practice, practice**.

As a golfer, I have experienced performances you have had in snooker.  Some days, I'm playing well. Other days, not so much. You have been playing snooker for 4 months. I have been playing golf for 15+ years.

[We're sitting here talking about **practice**, not a game](http://espn.go.com/blog/playbook/fandom/post/_/id/2026/allen-iversons-practice-rant-10-years-later). During **practice**, you get an idea of what you have to work with a given performance (akin to "one day I can see clearly the point I have to aim at ... the following day I can't visualize the shots") and an opportunity to further understand how you perform.

If you are in a less-than-favorable situation (in your case, can't visualize the shot), **practice** will help you mitigate it. Mind you, mitigation doesn't necessarily mean "strive for peak performance," but it will help turn an unfavorable situation into something manageable and turn a potentially bad performance into something better.

To be more consistent overall, **practice** will give you the opportunity to continue to do what you are doing well, and improve on what you are not doing so well. You will never arrive, because what you are doing well now and what you need to improve on will change and swap over time.

Main points:

- **Practice**
- Understand your style of play and embrace it
- Learn how to mitigate less-than-favorable situations
- Continue to do what you are doing well and improve on what you are not doing so well

Hopefully, with these points, you can be more consistent in snooker (or any sport you're playing in).

Comment: +1. Good advice. Consistency comes with practice. that said, there's some good Billiards specific advice at this page: http://billiards.colostate.edu/threads/advice.html

Comment: Well, believe me, but this is exactly what I'm trying to do at the moment :). During my practice sessions I try to address my weakest shots and repeat them many times. I say "I try" because it's hard for me to find enough time (read "the right amount of") to put into practice, for I'm also busy with study and such. So perhaps I should be more patient and see what it'll be 8 months from now. Cheers!

Comment: Not that you're doing this, but repeating your "weakest" shots is a moot point if they're not fundamentally sound...so I'd address your weakest shot, make sound changes if necessary, then repeat. Also, I can relate to your lack of time to practice...same with me!

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, every player goes through the same situation and all it comes down to your straight cueing and your stance. It is very important to learn the basic style of snooker which includes your grip and position of your elbow arm and wrist which should be straight to perfection in every shot you play in snooker. My suggestion would be to stick with the basic style and try to practice straight blues with aiming in the middle of cue ball. Remember it is very important to aim in the center of cue ball that's how you start learning the stun shots and you get better and better every time you play. Good player knows while cueing that it's gonna be a successful shot because of the feel he gets by cueing straight and follow the basics. Also it is not a bad option to skip a day if u are feeling worst.

Answer (score -3):

It sometimes really happens that you completey feel lost with your angles and your aiming,and the only cure for this what I have felt in myself is that i skip few days, it really helps my self improve :)